# How to configure Run Configuration to execute Main function in JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, configuration, program-entry-point, rider

I am having troubles configuring my Rider project configuration to run my Main function when I'd like to run the project (which is a simple Console App). Since I am new to the whole C# environment, I am kinda struggling here. What do I need to do, to simply execute the Main function from the IDE?

File: StockApplication.cs

```cs
namespace StockApplication
{
    public class StockApplication
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
             Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

There's also a csproj-File:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Configuration setting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just select the project and click on run button

[Just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4k3a.png)

[Select your project in configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSUhb.png)